Render API data points within a boundary
I am currently trying to find all the speed limits of roads within the Birmingham area. I have the API key from OS and set up the WFS Connection successfully. But what I have noticed is that it does not fully render in all the points, with large gaps of data then a warning about the API not being able to load more. The main cause of this (I hope) is that the API is for all of the UK and even though I have it only set to render within the view extent, it still captures a lot of the external areas of Birmingham.
Is it possible to just render what is within the boundary without it even pulling all the rest of the API data?
I have looked around a lot before coming here and I can't seem to see anything that answers what I need. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

You should be able to send/set up  a query that just retrieves data of interest.  Use the  SQL tool in the WFS Server connections. QGIS will convert this into the correct WFS query syntax

Perfect thank you! I'm not very good at using SQL but at least I know it is possible so I can start from there! I'll report back if I get it to work
